# Why "Split" is not a member function of type "string" in Go?

Tags: algorithm, go

Here are some snippets when you want to split a string with some specific delimiter in different languages:

```
# python
s = 'a,b,c,d,e'
tokens = s.split(',')

// javascript
let s = 'a,b,c,d,e'
let tokens = s.split(',')

// go
s := "a,b,c,d,e"
tokens := strings.Split(s, ",")
```

As you can see, "split" is a member function of type string in Python and Javascript, but not in Go.
I am wondering why is that, it seems like STL in CPP, why the functions to manipulate an instance of a type are not member functions of that type, it seems easy to implement them in Go, like:

```
// go
func (s *string) Split(d string) []string {
  // here goes the code to split s with d given
}
```

what is the reason it is designed this way?

Comment: For what it's worth, `split` was originally a [library routine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) in Python as well.

Comment: go authors don't want to clutter the programming language with things which weren't absolutely necessary, so if there is some need for something you will get them through stdlib.

Comment: The more general question is "Why don't the basic Go types have any methods?" That's likely for consistency. If Split was a method, you'd expect Join to be a method of `[]string`, but that would require string slices to be special instead of just another slice type.

Comment: Because Go doesn't buy into the "everything is an object" mentality.  Thankfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As you can see, "split" is a member function of type string in python and javascript, but not in golang.

That seems to have been so from the very beginning: [commit 729bc5c, Sept 2008, for Go1](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/729bc5c0c78d91435dd44bfcf40a8a2c631e14d2/src/lib/strings.go#L65-L85) is the first commit with any mention of a `string Split()` function.

> rudimentary string utilities.

Those functions were considered "utilities", and not part of the [predeclared string type '`string`' itself](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types).

It was documented soon after in [commit 0f7306b, March 2009, still Go1](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/0f7306b78ca278a88be1f131a446a2aceb68d73d)

```
// Split returns the array representing the substrings of s separated by string sep. Adjacent
// occurrences of sep produce empty substrings.  If sep is empty, it is the same as Explode.
func Split(s, sep string) []string {
```

You can see it used for the first time in [commit 5eae3b2, April 2009](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5eae3b21025169bfa39fc42d0dfcc997acab8e9d) in  [`func LookPath(file string) (string, *os.Error) {`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5eae3b21025169bfa39fc42d0dfcc997acab8e9d/src/lib/exec.go#L195-L217)

The same approach was use for byte with bytes: [commit 7893322, June 2009; Go1](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/78933226f114c5c9e6de5addd693d86a7724f2f4), with a [similar Split() function](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/78933226f114c5c9e6de5addd693d86a7724f2f4/src/lib/bytes/bytes.go#L90-L111).

> add a bytes package analogous to the strings package.

The general idea is: you can change that utility function without changing the value type itself.
See [commit 30533d6, June 2009](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/30533d607a3e10ae1a688ea88ee5976115681cba):

> Change `strings.Split`, `bytes.Split` to take a maximum substring `count` argument.
>
> ```
> func Split(s, sep []byte, n int) [][]byte
> ```

An even more drastic evolution:[commit ebb1566, June 2011](http://ebb1566a46f2f5b2c06ef0f7ad5f7084dce0aed9)

> `strings.Split`: make the default to split all.
>   Change the signature of Split to have no count, assuming a full split, and rename the existing `Split` with a count to `SplitN`.

The other idea is to keep using `string`, while possibly removing dependencies to those utility functions when you don't need them (as in [commit 35ace1d, Nov. 2009](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/35ace1d1f51e86d3f021d49e61431d39ecee9f6f): "remove dependencies on `strconv` and `strings`")

It also allows to *add* more related function, without touching string itself.
See [commit 5d436b9, Nov. 2009](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5d436b9defd0d36436bc22f9852b3e5e7446f5eb): lines := `strings.SplitAfter(text, "\n", 0)`, which uses `Split()`.

Another advantage: you can optimize those functions independently of `string` itself, allowing for duplicate 'Split' function to be replaced by `strings.Split()`.
See [commit f388119, March 2013, Go 1.1](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/f38811979cefe7cd61b34c5580e2d10f65f243db)

> ### `go/printer`: use `strings.Split` instead of specialized code
>
> With the faster strings package, the difference between the specialized code and strings.Split is in the noise:
>
> ```
> benchmark         old ns/op    new ns/op    delta
> BenchmarkPrint     16724291     16686729   -0.22%
> ```

The opposite case is also true: replacing strings.Split by a simpler code, as in [commit d0c9b40, Sept. 2015, Go 1.6](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/d0c9b40964f1951d2684545f1a6df64be899d26d)

> ### mime: Remove an allocation in word decoding.
>
> This fixes a `TODO` in `(*WordDecoder).Decode` by replacing a call to `strings.Split` with simple prefix/suffix checking and some custom slicing.
>
> Benchmark results:
>
> ```
> benchmark                    old ns/op     new ns/op     delta
> BenchmarkQEncodeWord-8       740           693           -6.35%
> BenchmarkQDecodeWord-8       1291          727           -43.69%
> BenchmarkQDecodeHeader-8     1194          767           -35.76%
> ```

(same idea in [commit ecff943, Sept. 2017, Go 1.11](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ecff94311d793dcb4c590690473aa1421f549f03))